# Fermions with no arrows in Tikz Feynman diagrams

Tags: tikz-feynman

I'm trying to get fermion lines **without** arrows, but I can't find a good documentations. Here is my code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{feynman}
    \vertex (a1) {};
    \vertex [below right=of a1] (b);
    \vertex [below left=of b](a2);
    \vertex [right=of b](c);
    \vertex [above right=of c](d1);
    \vertex [below right=of c](d2);


    \diagram* {
      (a1) -- [gluon] (b),
      (a2) -- [gluon] (b) -- [gluon] (c),
      (c) -- [fermion, without arrow](d1),
      (c) -- [fermion](d2)

    };
  \end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

which produces the following image.

[image]

I appreciate your help.

Comment: I like people who draw time on `x` axis in Feynman diagrams.

Comment: Does ` [fermion, -]` help?

Comment: no, it doesn't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `fermion` as line style. The *feynmf* package supports others, the one you are looking for is `vanilla` or `plain`. Change your code as above:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-feynman}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{feynman}
    \vertex (a1) {};
    \vertex [below right=of a1] (b);
    \vertex [below left=of b](a2);
    \vertex [right=of b](c);
    \vertex [above right=of c](d1);
    \vertex [below right=of c](d2);

    \diagram* {
      (a1) -- [gluon] (b),
      (a2) -- [gluon] (b) -- [gluon] (c),
      (c) -- [plain](d1), % Here is the change
      (c) -- [plain](d2)  % And here
    };
  \end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: perfect! thank you.